# difference in memory storage of pointer and reference member varible

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

What is the difference between the memory held by a reference and a pointer member variable?

Suppose I have a class A and class B. Class A has a member variable as a reference, while class B has a member variable as a pointer to a external object.

What will be the difference between the size of each class? Which is better when 1000s of objects of class A/B are required to be created?

Comment: Although not required by the standard, most compilers implement references using pointers.

Comment: Use `sizeof` of the `A` and `B` instances to check? And remember that there are other things to consider if you need to use a pointer or a reference, and that the size is seldom an issue (unless you're on a severely memory constrained system). Also, one should seldom use raw non-owning pointers these days, but rather smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` (or `std::weak_ptr` depending on use-case).

Comment: Note that with a reference non-static member, a compiler won't auto-generate assignment operators. Which might hinder, e.g., putting instances into `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference between the memory held by a reference and a pointer member variable?

The difference is that the reference member must be initialized in the constructor function, but for the pointer member variable, we can leave it uninitialized.

Generally, the reference is treated as the same as a pointer by compilers like GCC and Clang. So the storage size is the same: `sizeof(char*)`